# Best practices for other Laravel package resources?

Tags: php, laravel, package

I'm working on a package that uses a bunch of stub file templates for a custom CRUD generator command. So these are not views, but a collection of templates for models, controllers, etc.

Now, I know that my package views should publish to the `resources/views/vendor/package` folder:

```
$this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../resources/views' => resource_path('views/kjdion84/turtle')], 'views');
```

But what about resources that are not views? For example, I want to make a `crud` folder in the `resources` folder.

Should I put them in `resources/vendor/package/crud`, `resources/crud/vendor/package`, or just `resources/crud`?

What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

imo `resources/vendor/package/crud` would be the cleanest approach:

- avoids possible conflicts with existing files that might be there
- bundles all resources that belong to the package in the same folder
- avoids cluttering the resource file tree from the top